Web-scraping from video player
There's an anime website with several web-players in <iframe>-tag. I can easily find direct video link using "Network" from devtools. I need to download source video from web-player so I can watch it later offline, but finding links and downloading videos 1 by 1 by hand is exhausting when you need to get many of them. How can I automate it in a way I provide a link to anime page on the website and then program lets me download all of episodes (e.g. https://animejoy.ru/tv-serialy/3647-provozhayuschaya-v-posledniy-put-friren1.html)? I have no clue how to realize it. What direction should I dig?
I don't ask for code or something but It'd be nice if you told me general steps I have to perform in order to achieve described result.

I guess the simple answer (without code) is, you need to automate your manual steps.
I would recommend looking into puppeteer or maybe even playwright could work for that.
